# Moving needle of Gauge control in DotNetBar

Tags: vb.net

In DotNetBar I want to change needle value and make it move around Circular Gauges,but I cannot do it. In another component(AGauge) it can be done easily:
 AGauge1.Value += 1 
but it has some limitations (eg. no Vertical Gauge and not good preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this : http://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=989

I think this holds all your wonder (if this is the good control)...

Especially this:

> Value – The value of the Pointer.  This is the interval value the
>   Pointer is “pointing” to.
>
> Note, setting this value programmatically will cause the on screen
>   Pointer display to be dampened – if DampeningSweepTime has been set to
>   a non-zero value. If programmatic dampening is not desired, you can
>   set the Pointer Value via the ValueEx property.
>
> ValueEx – The value of the Pointer.  This is the interval value the
>   Pointer is “pointing” to.
>
> Note that setting this value programmatically will cause the on screen
>   Pointer display be updated immediately – no matter if
>   DampeningSweepTime has been set to a non-zero value or not. If
>   programmatic dampening is desired, you can set the Pointer Value via
>   the Value property.

Comment: Tanx,but there is no code example for doing what I said.I mean my control doesnt have most of Pointer Properties.

Comment: From the link below, you could do something like that : aGauge.StartAngle = 0; aGauge.Angle = 'Value'; and aGauge.EndAngle= 270;  To do what you said...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if it works for you

```
MyGaugeControl.SetPointerValue("MyScaleName", "MyPointerName", (double)[Value To Set]);
```

assuming

Gauge Name, Scale Name and Pointer name are respectively MyGaugeControl, MyScaleName and MyPointerName respectively.